# Why I am getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when I deploy my Spring application in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, autowired, spring-4

I am working with Spring and Spring Data JPA. When deploying my application in Tomcat I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
 private com.service.MyService com.controller.MyController.myService; nested exception 
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'MyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
 private com.repository.MyRepository com.service.MyService.myRepository; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
 [com.repository.MyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies 
 as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The following are my code:

**MyController.java**

```
package com.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.domain.MyEntity;
import com.service.MyService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(MyController.ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH)
public class MyController{

    public static final String ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/test";

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<MyEntity> getAll() {
        return myService.getAll();
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
package com.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.domain.MyEntity;
import com.repository.MyRepository;

@Service(value = "MyService")
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public List<MyEntity> getAll() {
        return myRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
package com.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import com.domain.MyEntity;

public interface MyRepository extends Repository<MyEntity, Long> {

    public List<MyEntity> findAll();
}

}
```

**MyApplication-context.xml**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.repository" /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.service" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: did you annotated implementation class of `MyRepository` with `@Repository`?

Comment: Add the @Repository annotation to your repository and give it a go.  Since you're using the old school means of component scanning your repositories, you'll need to identify them to Spring

Comment: @Arpit: OP uses Spring Data, which generates the implementation. He cannot annotate the repository.

Comment: Shouldn`t it be public List<User> findAll(); when Repository<User,Long> of User Type is defined. why List<MyEntity> ??

Comment: How is this related to Spring Boot? Also adding `<context:annotation-config />` doesn't add a thing as that is already covered by `<context:component-scan />`.

Comment: @dur with Spring Data, the annotation should be on the interface

Comment: Getting error not because of my description in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing your repository annotated. That might be the reason why Spring couldn't create a bean for MyRepository during component scan. Annotate it with `@Repository`